# ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have a custom control that has the following prototype.

```
Type.registerNamespace('Demo');

Demo.CustomTextBox = function(element) {
    Demo.CustomTextBox.initializeBase(this, [element]);
}

Demo.CustomTextBox.prototype = {

    initialize: function() {
    Demo.CustomTextBox.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

        this._onblurHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onBlur);

        $addHandlers(this.get_element(),
                     {
                         'blur': this._onBlur
                     },
                     this);
    },

    dispose: function() {
        $clearHandlers(this.get_element());

        Demo.CustomTextBox.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    _onBlur: function(e) {
        if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
            alert(this.get_element().value);
        }
    }
}

Demo.CustomTextBox.registerClass('Demo.CustomTextBox', Sys.UI.Control);

if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

How can i raise a post back event to the server in the _onBlur method?

Cheers

Rohan

Comment: Updating the question title to describe the question (instead of just ASP.NET Ajax) would probably gather more views/answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the __doPostBack method to do this, which has a signature of:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)
```

So it would be something along the lines of:

```
__doPostBack(this.get_element().id, 0);
```

Or you can optionally pass an argument along with the event if desired.